# How to use restrict access in apache?

Tags: apache-http-server

the httpd.conf is:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AuthName "Protected autons"
        AuthType Basic
        AuthUserFile /usr/local/gdnsplus_autons/sbin/apache.passwd
        require user test
</Directory>
```

Just the user of "test" can access the web site. Now, I want to add a 
function: If the user of "test" enter the wrong password after 5 times,
the user of "test" must wait for 10 minutes ,then "test" can enter again.

How to solve it by apache? Thank you.

Comment: This should be solved by the application implementing your login program, not apache itself.

Comment: Thank you."require user test" implement by apache. So, I want to do it by apache.

Comment: I would be implementing a login program much like Calvin suggested. Look at PHP / Perl / Python / Ruby scripts. That is what they are for.

Answer (score 0):

basically you are password protecting a web server directory. following this should get you started:

- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html#gettingitworking

Comment: Thank you,I have read it and do it in my httpd.conf. But, I need more function. Maybe I should implement it by PHP